# Tabs visible via url and onclick event

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

Am trying to create a tabbed interface in which the tabs can be visible via url and when clicked.
I have the following jQuery code

```
$(function() {
        var tabContent = $('.tab-content');
        var tabs = $('.stream-tabs li');
        var urlHash = window.location.hash;

        tabContent.not(hash).addClass('inactive');
        tabs.find('[href=' + hash + ']').addClass('active-tab');

        tabs.click(function() {
            $(this).addClass('active-tab').siblings().removeClass('active-tab');
            tabContent.hide();
            var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
            $(activeTab).fadeIn();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

This is my html markup

```
<ul class="stream-tabs">
                    <li><a href="#pheed-timeline">Pheed Timeline</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#directed-pheeds">Directed Pheeds</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#favourite-pheeds">Favourite Pheeds</a></li>
                </ul>
        <div class="tab-container">
            <div id="pheed-timeline" class="tab-content active-tab">
           Pheeed Timovmds
            </div>

            <div id="directed-pheeds" class="tab-content inactive">
           Directed pheeds
            </div>

            <div id="favourite-pheeds" class="tab-content inactive">
           favourite pheeds
            </div>
       </div>
```

When i click on the tab, nothing happens, the url just changes
What am i doing wrong

Comment: What does "visible via url and when clicked" mean? And before we can tell you what you're doing wrong, you should tell us what is going wrong to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
// get the current url or even the anchor of it
var path = document.location.toString();
// save current anchor in "anchor" var
var anchor = '#' + path.split('#')[1];   

// if no anchor is set, jquery will automatically set it to "undefined"
if(anchor != '#undefined') {
    // remove the class from the active tab
    $(".active").removeClass("active");  
    // set the active tab to the new one
    $(anchor).parent().addClass("active");
    // this hides the content of all tabs
    $(".tabContent").hide();  
    // show the new content of the clicked tab
    var content_show = $(anchor).attr("title");  
    $("#"+content_show).show();
}
```

I hope it's not too hard to understand. But it should be helpfull for your own code.

For better understanding, here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#" title="tabContent_1" class="tab">{{@lng.settings}}</a></li>
        <li><a href="#members" id="members" title="tabContent_2" class="tab">{{@lng.members}}</a></li>
        <li><a href="#milestones" id="milestones" title="tabContent_3" class="tab">{{@lng.milestones}}</a></li>
        <li><a href="#roles" id="roles" title="tabContent_4" class="tab">{{@lng.roles}}</a></li>
        <li><a href="#categories" id="categories" title="tabContent_5" class="tab">{{@lng.categories}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="tabContent" id="tabContent_1">
<!-- content here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.tab-content') !== class="tab-container"
```

`tab-content` vs `tab-container`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(this).addClass('active-tab').siblings().removeClass('active-tab');
```

this line adds these classes to li rather div's